# Find children objects missing parents objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a set of collection built in such a way that every object in the "children"(possible_child) collection should at least have a parent the parent collection (possible_parent). I would like to detect those children with no parent object.
As an example, if i find a child with a given country, year, season and season type without there should at least be a parent record with the same data.

I wrote the following query which i now see is wrong.

```
var childrenMissingParents = (from cl in possible_child
join pr in possible_parent on new
 {
   p1=cl.Country,
   p2=cl.Year,
   p3=cl.Season,
   p4=cl.SeasonType

  }

    equals
  new
  {
    p1=pr.Country,
    p2=pr.Year,
    p3=pr.Season,
    p4=pr.SeasonType
  }
into opr from spr in opr.DefaultIfEmpty()
where spr == null select cr).ToList();
```

Can someone suggest a better idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var childrenMissingParents = possible_child.Where(
    c => !possible_parent.Any(
        p => p.Country == c.Country
     && p.Year == c.Year
     && p.Season == c.Season
     && p.SeasonType == c.SeasonType));
```

Comment: Both answers solve my problem thousand thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, the following does what you want:

```
var orphanedItems = possible_child
    .Where(item => !possible_parent.Any(p =>
        (p.Year == item.Year) &&
        (p.Country == item.Country) &&
        (p.Season== item.Season) &&
        (p.SeasonType == item.SeasonType)));
```

Comment: correct and i just chose one of the working solutions. I could have chosen this one as well. Many thnaks

Answer (score 1):

You could use Where and Any to achieve your goal.

```
var childrenWithoutParent = possible_child.Where(child => !possible_parent.Any(p =>
                                                                   (p.Year == child.Year) &&
                                                                   (p.Country == child.Country) &&
                                                                   (p.Season == child.Season) &&
                                                                   (p.SeasonType == child.SeasonType)));
```

However, you can improve even more the read of your code, you could have a method in your child to compare to the parent:

```
public class Child
    {
        ....

        public bool IsEqualsTo(Parent parent)
        {
            return (this.Year == parent.Year) &&
                   (this.Country == parent.Country) &&
                   (this.Season == parent.Season) &&
                   (this.SeasonType == parent.SeasonType)));
        }
    }
```

This could improve the readability of your query.

```
  var childrenWithoutParent = possible_child
                                    .Where(child => !possible_parent.Any(p => child.IsEqualsTo(p));
```